# HttpCacheability.Server - Web Handler

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to cache a web handler that outputs javascript, the problem is in my web solution the server is not cache, but it does cache in a prototype project. Is there something like security or anything else that may force a call to executable code and not serve server cache back to the client?

This is what I am using, like I said this works fine in a prototype solution so it must be environmental:

```
        TimeSpan freshness = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 00);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        currentContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
        currentContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
        currentContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);


        currentContext.Response.ContentType = JAVASCRIPT_CONTENT_TYPE;
        currentContext.Response.Write(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem. In the code I was uing Response.OutputStream not Response.Write.